# Issue with login function using strcspn and fgets in C

Tags: c, authentication, fgets, strcmp

I'm trying to make a login function as part of a larger program, this is the dumbed down version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char username[50], password[50];
    char real_Username[] = "user", real_Password[] = "pass";
    int confirm_User, confirm_Pass;

    printf("Username ");
    fgets(username, 50, stdin);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Password ");
    fgets(password, 50, stdin);

    confirm_User = strcspn(username, real_Username);
    confirm_Pass = strcspn(password, real_Password);

    if (confirm_User == 0 && confirm_Pass == 0) {
        printf("Correct\n");
    } else {
        printf("Incorrect\n");
    }

    getch();
}
```

The result of `confirm_User` and `confirm_Pass` are still 0 in some cases when the user didn't enter the correct text. For example, entering `user` and `padd` will still count as correct input. How do I go about fixing this code?

Comment: The problem is the use of `strcspn()` function; read the manual of `strcspn()` to see what it does.

Comment: Also, why are you not checking the return of `fgets()`?

Answer (score 1):

There is some confusion here:

- `strcspn(s1, s2)` computes the number of characters at the start of `s1` not present in `s2`, which can be used to strip the newline from the buffer filled by `fgets()`.
- to compare strings, you should use `strcmp()`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char username[50] = "", password[50] = "";
    char real_Username[] = "user", real_Password[] = "pass";
    int confirm_User, confirm_Pass;

    printf("Username ");
    fgets(username, 50, stdin);
    // strip the trailing newline if any
    username[strcspn(username, "\n")] = '\0';

    printf("\n");
    printf("Password ");
    fgets(password, 50, stdin);
    // strip the trailing newline if any
    password[strcspn(password, "\n")] = '\0';

    confirm_User = strcmp(username, real_Username);
    confirm_Pass = strcmp(password, real_Password);

    if (confirm_User == 0 && confirm_Pass == 0) {
        printf("Correct\n");
    } else {
        printf("Incorrect\n");
    }

    getch();
}
```

Also note that it is preferable to disable echo when prompting the user for a password, but there is no portable way to do this.

Comment: Re first bullet point: ... computes the number of characters *at the start of* `s1` ...

Answer (score 0):

`strcspn` is not the right tool for this job.

It returns the number of characters at the start of the text which do not exist in the thing you're searching for, so something like:

```
strcspn ("password", "cap")
```

will give you zero, because the `p` in `cap` is found at the start of the string.

The correct function you should probably be using is `strcmp`, which compares two strings.

Answer (score 0):

Because both `pass` and `padd` starts with `p`, the return value of `strcspn` is:

> The length **of the initial part** of str1 not containing any of the
>   characters that are part of str2. This is the length of str1 if none
>   of the characters in str2 are found in str1. size_t is an unsigned
>   integral type.

Use `strcmp` instead, but don't forget to remove the trailing newline included by `fgets`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace strcspn() with strcmp() and all will be good.

Answer (score 0):

The C library function int strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2) compares the string pointed to, by str1 to the string pointed to by str2.

Therefore use strcmp() instead.

Answer (score 0):

U can also try this code to take password!!

```
// DEEPAK AHIRE
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    char arr[10];

    char c='a';
    int k=0;

    while( c != 32){

        c = getch();

        putch('*');

        arr[k++]=c;
    }

    printf("%s",arr);
    return 0;
}
```

And then use strcmp() function(Press space chracter(ASCII =  32) to break).